# How to validate input fields to take only color values in Angular 6

Tags: html, angular, mean-stack

I am implementing a web app using MEAN Stack and Angular 6. There I have an input field which takes color values from ngx-colorpicker. But these input fields allow me to take text inputs as well. If I use `<input type= 'color'>` then it opens a separate color picker and if I select a color it applies only to the middle part of the text field. What I want is to prevent entering text or numbers in these input fields. Does anyone has an idea to do it?

This is my input field.

```
<input type="text" nbInput [(colorPicker)]="colorRangeTraceArc" [cpPosition]="'right'" [cpOutputFormat]="'rgba'[style.background]="colorRangeTraceArc"
    formControlName="colorRTC" name="colorRangeTraceArc" style="width: 100px" (colorPickerChange)="onChangeColorRTA($event)" />
```

Comment: Can you use type="color" ?

Comment: It does not work. I updated the question.

Comment: @Bene: it works only in Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use keydown event on textbox to block any input in the textbox.

Here is the HTML code :

```html
(keydown)="keyDown($event)"
```

Here is the TS code :

```js
 keyDown(event:any){
    return false;
  }
```

Please check first textbox in the [stackbliz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-mpj9lp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it did not work. In your  stackblitz example also I tried to enter text characters in color the input. It allows. What I want is not to take text inputs in the input field. It should take only colors.

Comment: Color  means color values picked through the color picker.

Comment: I have editied my answer, please check and let me know, is this helpful for you or not?